# How to add tags / debug info to solid context during runtime, that can be retrieved from a failure_hook?

Tags: dagster

First, let me give my use case.

I have a solid that runs and attempts with particular inputs and configuration. I also have a failure hook that logs to lets say, slack.

During the execution of the solid step, I want to add some information to the context (perhaps selected input variable values, etc), perhaps in the form of a dictionary. And then I want the failure_hook to be able to retrieve these for whatever error logging it performs.

What is the best way to implement this pattern?

Answer (score 1):

(dagster team member here) We are working on making the thrown exception available on the hook context which will be one way to approach this, once thats available.

For now, you can take advantage of the fact that solid hooks are run in process with the solid execution itself, so you can use something like a process global variable to track information you want the hook to read and report.